# SQL query - Select resulting records where a value appears 25+ times

Tags: sql, salesforce

I have the following query working correctly:

```
select  o.SubscriberKey , o.JobID,  CAST(o.EventDate AS Date) AS 'OpenDate'
FROM _Open o
where o.IsUnique = 1 and (o.EventDate between 'Jun 06 2018' and 'Dec 06 2018')
GROUP BY o.SubscriberKey , o.JobID, o.EventDate
```

Now I need to modify it to only select SubscriberKeys that appear in the results 25 times or more. I think I can use a Count function, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select o.*
from (select o.SubscriberKey, o.JobID, CAST(o.EventDate AS Date) AS OpenDate,
             count(*) over (partition by  o.SubscriberKey) as cnt
      from _Open o
      where o.IsUnique = 1 and (o.EventDate between 'Jun 06 2018' and 'Dec 06 2018')
      group by o.SubscriberKey, o.JobID, o.EventDate
     ) o
where cnt >= 25
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this will work out. I'll just have to check the results and make sure it gives us what we need.